# Using window function in redshift to aggregate conditionally

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with following data:
[image: input data]

Link to test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dce01/1/0

I want to aggregate the items column (using `listagg`) for each group in gid in sequence as specified by seq column based on the condition that aggregation ends when pid becomes `0` again for a group.

i.e.
for group g1, there would be 2 aggregations; 1 for seq 1-3 and another for sequence 4-6; since for group g1, the pid becomes 0 for seq 4.

I expect the result for the given example to be as follows (*Please note that `seq` in result is the min value of seq for the group where the pid becomes 0*):
[image: result]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I need to run the query on redshift. However, since sqlfiddle has no option for redshift engine, I created the test data with postgres db for the exact same reason that you pointed out (about them sharing common roots). Additionally, postgres query can be run with some mods in redshift, eg. `listagg` alternative for postgres would be `string_agg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question as a gaps and island problem, where you want to group together adjacent rows having the same `gid` untiil a `pid` having value `0` is met.

Here is one way to solve it using a window sum to define the groups: basically, a new island starts everytime a pid of `0` is met. The rest is just aggregation:

```
select
    gid,
    min(seq) seq,
    listagg(items, ',') within group(order by seq) items
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when pid = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by gid order by seq) grp
    from mytable t
) t
group by gid, grp
order by gid, grp
```

Comment: thanks... that worked... i have put the working postgres version of query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dce01/11)

Comment: we also need to add `rows unbounded preceding` after order by clause in sum aggregation without which redshift outputs error message "Error running query: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause"

Answer (score 1):

it's gaps and islands problem:

```
with
 subgroup_ids as (
    select *, sum(case when pid=0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by gid order by seq) as subgroup_id
    from tablename
)
select gid, subgroup_id, listagg(items,',')
from subgroup_ids
group by 1,2
```